# Page behaviour modifying google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I really want to make google mail by default bottom posting, in other words, I want the cursor in the textarea in a reply message to move automatically to the bottom.

Is this possible with google chrome extensions?
Have you maybe any other suggestions?

Problems I'm facing:

1. Run the extension script when gmail is fully loaded
2. The target textarea is in it's own iframe, is it possible to access it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use the [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) feature of a Chrome extension in order to manipulate the 
page a user is browsing. Your content script code will run in the context of the web page the user is browsing, and it may interact with the host page almost without limit.

Manipulating Gmail might be a bit trickier than most other pages, due to its dynamic nature. Consider using the [jQuery .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to make it easy bind to the elements you want to manipulate.

With regard to iframes, you just have to turn on the ["all_frames" option](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration) in your manifest, which "controls whether the content script runs in all frames of the matching page, or only the top frame."

(I know this question is a bit stale, but I thought maybe you'd still appreciate an answer.)

I hope that helps.